# Problems with SelectedValue, SelectedIndex while data binding to a ComboBox c++/cx XAML Metro app

Tags: xaml, data-binding, combobox, microsoft-metro, c++-cx

How can I use the value of the ComboBox's selected element in the following code?

C++:

```
namespace testtesttest
{
[Windows::UI::Xaml::Data::Bindable]
public ref class Wrapper sealed : Windows::UI::Xaml::Data::INotifyPropertyChanged
{
public:
    Wrapper()
    {
        // the index of the selected element of the combobox when the application starts
        m_selectedElement = 2;

        m_myStringArray = ref new Platform::Collections::Vector<int>(3);
        // 1, 2, and 4 in the combobox list
        m_myStringArray->SetAt(0,1);
        m_myStringArray->SetAt(1,2);
        m_myStringArray->SetAt(2,4);
    }

    virtual event Windows::UI::Xaml::Data::PropertyChangedEventHandler^ PropertyChanged;


    property Windows::Foundation::Collections::IVector<int>^ MyStringArray
    {
        Windows::Foundation::Collections::IVector<int>^ get() { return m_myStringArray; }
    }

    property int SelectedElement
    {
        int get() { return m_selectedElement; }
        void set(int value) { m_selectedElement = value; RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedElement"); }
    }
protected:
    void RaisePropertyChanged(Platform::String^ propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, ref new Windows::UI::Xaml::Data::PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
private:
    Platform::Collections::Vector<int>^ m_myStringArray;
    int m_selectedElement;
};
}
```

XAML:

```
<TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
           Height="73" Margin="50,436,0,0" 
           TextWrapping="Wrap" 
           Text="{Binding Path=SelectedElement}" 
           VerticalAlignment="Top" 
           Width="200"/>
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyStringArray}" 
          SelectedIndex="{Binding Path=SelectedElement}"  
          HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
          Height="50" Margin="369,50,0,0" 
          VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="286"/>
```

I tested other bindings and they worked. I am setting the DataContext right.
The m_selectedElement = 2 in the constructor sets the selected element in the combobox to the 3rd in the list. The get() method of the SelectedElement property gets called, but the set() method doesn't. I checked this by placing a breakpoint. What am I doing wrong?

Also, is it possible to bind a Platform::Array^ to a ComboBox? 
I tried using Platform::Array < Platform::String ^>^ and also Platform::Array < int>^ and I couldn't get it work. STL containers also didn't work. What are the other possible containers that can bind to a combobox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
SelectedIndex="{Binding Path=SelectedElement}"
```

to

```
SelectedIndex="{Binding Path=SelectedElement, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

You need a two-way binding if you want the UI to update your ViewModel.

You can only use WinRT components in bindings (ref classes/structs, enum classes). Using Platform::Collections::Vector is generally the right choice when it's used for binding, especially because it also implements IObservableVector. STL containers don't work because they cannot travel across the ABI.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. I made other binding tests and they worked both ways without me specifying the Mode so I assumed that TwoWay was implicit.

Comment: Nope, bindings are **not** implicitly TwoWay in WinRT. They all default to OneWay. Are you sure the your binding tests worked both ways? Also, if the answer works, the convention is to accept it by clicking on the big check-mark outline to the left of the answer.

Comment: no, you are right. I wasn't binding both ways. I was just changing the property when I was clicking a button. And I didn't know about the checkmark ... my first question. I would vote it up too but don't have the reputation. Thanks